# Using International Driving license in Spain, while having residence Permit from Germany

Tags: germany, resident-permit, driving-license, spain

I am a Student from Indonesia, and currently studying in Germany. On March I am going to travel to Spain, and planning to rent a car there. I have a valid International Driving License and Indonesian Driving License. But having a Residence Permit (Aufenthaltstitel) from Germany, means I can't use my IDL in Germany. But can I still use my IDL to drive in Spain for Holiday?

Comment: You have a valid Indonesian driver's license, and an IDL that translates the Indonesian script into Latin letters. If Spain allows tourists to drive using valid licenses from their countries of origin, why do you think you will have a problem here?

Comment: Why can't you use your IDL in Germany?  (I suspect it is more to do with "only for the first six months", than "because you have a residence permit").

Comment: @David One possible reason is that the OP is a Schengen resident.  As such, their foreign licence may only be valid for the first ?month?, ?six months? in Schengen.  It rather depends how integrated the rules for drivers licences are.

Comment: I have already registered in Germany for more than 6 Months. Meaning my IDL in Germany is no longer useable. But if I go to Spain or other countries in Schengen Area as Tourist, will my IDL still useable?

Comment: The rules on driving licence recognition aren't integrated across Schengen at all. So I suspect the answer is that it's fine to do this.

Comment: @MartinBonner Thanks for the comment. I agree that the actual answer to the OP's question will be determined by Spanish law, and (as MJeffryes notes) how Spanish law integrates across the Schengen area.